# Isotope Issue: Masonry Column Width Twice as large as it was defined in code

Tags: jquery, grid, fluid-layout, jquery-isotope

This is very weird and very throughouly researched on the web by me. I didn't find any solutions.

The jQuery says:

> $container.isotope({
>      itemSelector : '.post',
>      masonry: {
>        columnWidth: 250,
>      }
>   });

The .post's style says:

> .post {
>     width:250px;
>   }

When Isotope defines the .post's positions, the second column is positioned 500px from the left of the page. The third column, 1000px from the left of the page. It's like each column is getting width of 500px.

The link is: http://asimob.tv

Getting bald and hypertensive with this. I would really, really appreciate some help. Please!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, it seems that the "columnWidth" property is NOT just the width of the element(.post for example) but rather the width + the margins.

So the columnWidth should be equal to element width + (margin x 2).

Hopefully this might be helpful to someone who stumbles on this issue.

Comment: thank you, thank you, thank you. just spent a good 30 minutes banging my head against the wall on this. silly.

Comment: Glad it helped someone! :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the columnWidth:250 in the options section when you initiate Isotope.

Comment: Thanks very much for answering. I've tried to remove that, but what happens then is that isotope will automatically define the column width to the first element found in the container. Since I'm intending to have multiple size boxes, when the first box happen to be larger than the others the columns get to large for the rest of the boxes. Just set isotope like you suggested in http://asimob.tv